# Cómo puedo desactivar estas sugerencias de Visual Studio Code

Tags: vscode

[image: Captura de la sugerencia]

Quiero que no aparezca estas sugerencia, pero el intellisense quiero que siga normal

Comment: Te refieres a visual studio code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ve a File -> Preferences -> Settings y busca "hints". Desmarca la opción "Parameter Hints".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @atencio947 **No** des las `gracias`. La forma de agradecerlo es marcando la respuesta como *aceptada*, pulsando en el símbolo del *check* ( ✔ ) a la izquierda de la respuesta, justo debajo de los votos.

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción es editar el archivo de configuración de usuario y desactivarlo ahí.
PAra localizarlo escribe en la barra de búsqueda de VSCode "editor.hover..." y edita el archivo Json.

```
"editor.hover.enabled": false,
```