eliminar la recomendaciones de parámetros en vscode, me sale esta pestaña

He intentado desactivar las pistas/sugerencias de vscode pensando que era eso, y sigue pasando esta situación, si alguien me podría dar la solución se los agradecería.
cada vez que realizo un System.out.println(); al entrar dentro de los paréntesis me aparecen como recomendaciones de lo que debe ir dentro de los paréntesis, y para que me deje de salir esa pestañita tengo que darle escape.

Hola, intenta ir a File -> preferences ->  Settings y busca "hints". Desmarca la opción "Parameter Hints" y me dices si asi lo conseguistes, revisa si las respuestas de esta pregunta te ayudan https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/233124/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-desactivar-estas-sugerencias-de-visual-studio-code

¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? Cómo puedo desactivar estas sugerencias de Visual Studio Code
